# C++ 2D vector sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, 2d

I want to sort the numbers within a 2D vector (10x100).

My idea is to sort it first by rows, and then find the smallest number in the first column and save it in a new 1D vector, then delete the smallest one in the column, and so on till the last number.

My code goes like this but it doesn't work.

```
vector <vector <int> > vec(10, vector <int> (0));// already sorted by rows.
vector <int> datafinal;

for( int row=0; row < vec.size(); row++){
    int mini = vec[0][0];
    if (vec[row][0]< mini) {
        datafinal.push_back(mini);
        vec[row].erase(vec[row].begin());
    }
}

for (int k=0; k< datafinal.size(); k++){
    cout << datafinal[k] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems to be fundamentally broken. Since it's possible for the same row to have the smallest value every time, eventually that row will be completely empty while the remaining rows remain untouched. There will no longer be a "smallest one" in the first column, since one of the rows will, by definition, be empty, and your logic will result in undefined behavior. The shown code also has an obvious bug, but since your overall logic appears to be quite broken, that's a moot point. Figure out the correct logic first, then start working on the implementation.

Comment: could you please show me some logic? i am just a beginner.

Comment: Unfortunately, only you know the logic you need to sort your matrix. I have no idea what your matrix is for, and how you intend to use it. Although you might be a beginner in C++, this has nothing to do with C++. The logic would be the same were it ***implemented*** in C++, Java, Python, Perl, or any other language. You need to define, in logical terms, how you need to sort your matrix, first. And only then translate it into code.

Comment: You don't need to sort a row to get the smallest item in a row.  Just use `std::min_element(vec[row].begin(), vec[row].end());` to get an iterator to the smallest item in a row `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and logic example, I feel like this is what you're trying to do:

- You desire to sort the entire matrix/2d vector such that reading from left to right and top to bottom the martix/2d vector will read in ascending/descending order.

In this case, you could treat the entire matrix/2d vector as though its a set of N elements for sorting, but you will have to ensure that you properly place/replace your data in a 2d format.

An example of this would be:

[3, 5, 1] 
[1, 3, 1] 
[12, 4, 1]

This could be handled as standard array/vector if you represent it as: **[3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 12, 4, 1]**

By treating it as a standard array/vector, you could perform a normal sorting function on the set.

Then to convert it back into a matrix/2d format you'd be able to iterate through the set and each time you've read the number of elements that make up the size of a row N, you'd move to a new row.

Comment: Why? What is the meaning of the value? How is it used? Do you just need the smallest for the whole array?, or does each row/column minimum have some meaning?